# Get definition of function, sequence, type etc. in Postgresql with SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I need the create scripts for PostgreSQL database objects.

I have not access to pg_dump. So I have to get everything with SQL queries. How could I do this?

Comment: For a single function see `\ef` which "edits [a] function in the form of a CREATE FUNCTION command" (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html)

Answer (score 61):

To get the definition of a function use `pg_get_functiondef()`:

```
select pg_get_functiondef(oid)
from pg_proc
where proname = 'foo';
```

There are similar functions to retrieve the definition of an index, a view, a rule and so on. For details see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

Getting the definition of a user type is a bit more tricky. You will need to query `information_schema.attributes` for that:

```
select attribute_name, data_type
from information_schema.attributes
where udt_schema = 'public'
  and udt_name = 'footype'
order by ordinal_position;
```

From that you need to re-assemble the `create type` statement.

For more details you will need to read through the documentation of the system catalog: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html

But you should prefer `information_schema` views if they return the same information.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have around 8 user types in my database but when I look in information_schema.attributes there is 0 rows. Any idea?

Comment: @John: no idea. Can you post the definition of those types? To get more detailes statements follow Erwin's advice and startup psql using the -E switch to see which statemtents it's using. Most probably something involving pg_type and pg_attribute.

Answer (score 16):

You will find [**`psql -E`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) instrumental in your quest for those queries.
It displays the queries `psql` uses when executing its backslash-commands - like `\df+ myfunc` for details about this function.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a complete sample query using pg_get_functiondef:

```
WITH funcs AS (
  SELECT
    n.nspname AS schema
    ,proname AS sproc_name
    ,proargnames AS arg_names
    ,t.typname AS return_type
    ,d.description
    ,pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) as definition
  FROM pg_proc p
    JOIN pg_type t on p.prorettype = t.oid
    JOIN pg_description d on p.oid = d.objoid
    JOIN pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
  WHERE n.nspname = 'some_schema_name_here'
)
SELECT *
FROM funcs
;;
```

Note, you should obviously specify the schema name, (or "public" if you are using that schema)

Comment: Note, I prefer this format because I can use this query to search for functions containing specific text in the description (my basic function documentation) or in the function's definition.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do \sf to see the user defined function in psql

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    pp.proname,                                     --function name.
    pp.pronamespace::regnamespace::text AS schema,  --function located schema
    pg_get_functiondef(oid),                        --function def
    pg_get_function_arguments(oid),                 --(including default values).
    pg_get_function_identity_arguments(oid),        --This form omits default values.
    pg_get_function_result(oid)                     --Reconstructs the RETURNS clause of a function
FROM
    pg_proc pp
WHERE
    proname = 'eval_safe';
```

from [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html)

```
pg_get_functiondef ( func oid ) → text
```

> Reconstructs the creating command for a function or procedure. (This
> is a decompiled reconstruction, not the original text of the command.)
> The result is a complete CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION or CREATE OR
> REPLACE PROCEDURE statement.

```sql
pg_get_function_arguments ( func oid ) → text
```

> Reconstructs the argument list of a function or procedure, in the form
> it would need to appear in within CREATE FUNCTION (including default
> values).

```sql
pg_get_function_identity_arguments ( func oid ) → text
```

> Reconstructs the argument list necessary to identify a function or
> procedure, in the form it would need to appear in within commands such
> as ALTER FUNCTION. This form omits default values.

```sql
pg_get_function_result ( func oid ) → text
```

> Reconstructs the RETURNS clause of a function, in the form it would
> need to appear in within CREATE FUNCTION. Returns NULL for a
> procedure.