# Postgres SHOW CREATE Type

Tags: postgresql, types, sqldatatypes

I'm looking for a few ways to find a CREATE TYPE statement for an existing user defined type in a postgres (9.3.3) db.

So far I have tried 3 ways and seem to have failed on each:
1) An SQL Command?
 pg_catalog.get_pg_typdef does not seem to be implemented at this time.
2) A pg_dump sift?
 How does one dump a specific type? I don't see a type flag? I've tried "-s" for the schema only but I'd like to specify just the one type.
3) PgAdmin GUI
 The pgadmin gui is great! I'm running 1.18.1 And it seems to recognize that my user defined types exist (as dependencies of other known objects) but it does not show the create type SQL that I am looking for.

How do you overflowers find type definitions? I feel like I'm close with any of these.
Thanks much!

PostgreSQL 9.3.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2), 64-bit

Comment: Are you looking for a CREATE TYPE statement like the CREATE TABLE statements we can all see in pgAdmin? I'd try to dump the schema with pg_dump, and then search for the type's name: `grep -i "your-type-name" your-dump-file`. Is it a composite type, an enumerated type, a range type, or a base type?  Do you know how it was created?

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks for the quick reply... I can see it as a row reflected in the pg_catalog.pg_type table. (It has a typtype of "d") I think that means a domain? I was able to sift through the pg_dump of the public schema.

Comment: Why do you need the SQL code? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Yes, that's a domain. You use CREATE DOMAIN to create domains. You can find them in pgAdminIII by drilling down to a schema. (Most often the public schema. No guarantees.) Domains are one of the entries under each schema.

Comment: Unfortunately PostgreSQL's server-side dump facilities are bad-to-nonexistent. There are functions for a few things, like `pg_get_viewdef`, but most functionality is in `pg_dump`, and not easily re-used or accessed on fine granularity.

Comment: @DwayneTowell I have a few developers asking me about various objects in their database, specifically they are trying to build a few selective schemas into a docker image from our production database. These few schemas seem to have various dependencies to others that were not migrated. Frankly, I didn't even know that it was a domain I was asking about earlier. Thus I believe my questions should really be about identifying objects given random keywords from others. I know that postgres gives you a lot in system tables but my background is mostly mysql, so I have some homework to do.

Comment: @CraigRinger and Mike Sherrill Thanks for the feedback also! If anyone knows of a good roadmap around types, im all ears :) Thanks guys

Comment: You can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148914/get-definition-of-function-sequence-type-etc-in-postgresql-with-sql-query